# Eclipse execute some code when pause/resume button clicked

Tags: eclipse

I need somehow to send UDP datagram from eclipse to change state of external application which is used to simulate some environment for my embeded application on SoC. I need to reflect state of eclipse debuging (paused or resumed) to this app. How can i catch eclipse pause/resume button click and execute some code?

Comment: An Eclipse plugin can use a `IDebugEventSetListener` to listen to debug events.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've kick me in right direction.